# Duplicate Content in WMT even with rel canonical

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, seo, duplicate

I am desperate to find a solution for this problem.

I've read most of the posts here and on almost all related forums/sites on Magento Duplicates. I just cant find a solution for my problem.

We have a baby products online shop and run on Magento 1.9.1. 
I have set all of the Magento SEO built in optimization features. We don't have any SEO extensions.

My issue is with configurable products, like clothes and shoes.
I have set rel canonical for the products as directed by most people here, 301 redirect in case of accessing a child /variation. Only the main configurable is visible.
But Google insists in poing these child products are duplicates for title and description in WMT.
I've done all indicated to fix the problem, but the list of duplicates simply doesn't decrease. Right now I have about 2500 duplicates in WMT.

My volume of organic visits is ridiculous compared to my competitors of the same size, we are up and running since 2010, but moved to Magento by end of 2014. Decision was made based on Magento SEO features, but until today we had no luck growing organic visits.

I am desperate and if these visits don't grow we may be in trouble...  :-(

I am using this forum as my last chance to keep my shop up and running.

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image: WMT screenshot - Example]

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the source of these pages to confirm that the canonical tag is being rendered & with the correct value?

I just checked a child product view (http://www.4babies.com.br/catalog/product/view/id/5199) and it *is* displaying canonical URL correctly.

Can you check against old reports to see if, due to catalog admin activities, your URLS aren't constantly changing. A couple things make me think this: [your sitemap](http://www.4babies.com.br/sitemap.xml) is all out of whack, and it looks like the biggest offense is that trailing product ID at the end **which should not be part of your URLs** and is likely a bit of a race condition which I've seen in some stores which specifically affects configurable products. Some info / solution (caveat emptor like seriously for real):

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17716/5
- https://www.atwix.com/magento/duplicated-product-url-keys-in-community-edition/

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the feedback! Yes, it seems like the canonical tag is correct, I also re-checked and it´s pointing to the correct URL. Now that you mentioned, for some reason my sitemap is not updating at all , I am looking at the server providers to see if there is any cron issues. 
Regaring the rewrites, I believe it´s part of the main issue ( together with the sitemap problem),I had 10 million rewrites and I did upload over CSV file , and seems like Magento has problems with that.  
I will take a detalied look at the URL´s you sent while they seems to be related to the problem I have

Comment: *"I did upload [rewrites] over CSV file , and seems like Magento has problems with that"* - I can tell you that yes, almost certainly that is the origination of the problem. You may need a Magento dev/data expert to help extricate yourself from this mess. Not sure if the Atwix solution will be enough; worth a try though.